# Trying to get ng-model with no id using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

trying get a angular input field via Selenium wiht no luck. Any help is appreciated

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" id="" placeholder="Your ZIP Code" ng-model="zipCode" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 &amp;&amp; searchBySize()" maxlength="5">
```

trying with

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
zip = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input[ng-model="zipCode"]')))
```

This times out and all other attempts end with 'str' object is not callable

Please help. Thx

Answer (score 0):

i cant see anything wrong with your code but why can't you try another locator like below

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
zip = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[placeholder='Your ZIP Code']")))
```

Comment: I tried using 'placeholder' as well and still got the timeout. The page being Angular I'm sure has something to do with it, but I haven't been able to figure it out.